# GRPC and types import error in App Engine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I deployed my application in App engine successfully. However, when I try to access my API, I receive the following message:

> Error: Server Error
>   The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   Please try again in 30 seconds.

I'm unable to understand the cause of this issue, as it is coming from Datastore API. Can somebody please help me to troubleshoot this issue?

Below is all the relevant information.

Backtraces

When referred to root of the URL

```
2018-03-27 08:08:45,090 <root> [ERROR]
2018-03-27 16:08:45.099 HKT
Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-03-27 16:08:45.099 HKT
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/6baee03590d046f1_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/6baee03590d046f1_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/6baee03590d046f1_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
    __import__(cumulative_path)
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/web/app.py", line 6, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
    from web.routes import ROUTES_BLUEPRINT
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/web/routes.py", line 7, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
    from metadata.repository.gcp_clouddatastore import GCPCloudDataStore
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/metadata/repository/gcp_clouddatastore.py", line 8, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
    from google.cloud import datastore
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/lib/google/cloud/datastore/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
    from google.cloud.datastore.batch import Batch
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/lib/google/cloud/datastore/batch.py", line 24, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
    from google.cloud.datastore import helpers
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/lib/google/cloud/datastore/helpers.py", line 29, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
    from google.cloud.datastore_v1.proto import datastore_pb2
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/lib/google/cloud/datastore_v1/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
    from google.cloud.datastore_v1.gapic import datastore_client
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/lib/google/cloud/datastore_v1/gapic/datastore_client.py", line 18, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
    import google.api_core.gapic_v1.client_info
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/lib/google/api_core/gapic_v1/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
    from google.api_core.gapic_v1 import config
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/lib/google/api_core/gapic_v1/config.py", line 23, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
    import grpc
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/lib/grpc/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc as _cygrpc
2018-03-27 16:08:45.100 HKT
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initcygrpc)
2018-03-27 16:08:45.111 HKT
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

Accessing API other then root, shows me another backtrace

```
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
2018-03-27 08:13:41,377 <root> [ERROR] 
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/6baee03590d046f1_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/6baee03590d046f1_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/6baee03590d046f1_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
    __import__(cumulative_path)
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/web/app.py", line 6, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
    from web.routes import ROUTES_BLUEPRINT
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/web/routes.py", line 7, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
    from metadata.repository.gcp_clouddatastore import GCPCloudDataStore
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/metadata/repository/gcp_clouddatastore.py", line 8, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
    from google.cloud import datastore
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/lib/google/cloud/datastore/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
    from google.cloud.datastore.batch import Batch
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/lib/google/cloud/datastore/batch.py", line 24, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
    from google.cloud.datastore import helpers
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/lib/google/cloud/datastore/helpers.py", line 29, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
    from google.cloud.datastore_v1.proto import datastore_pb2
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~singapore-profile-dev2/20180327t160251.408595751204823647/lib/google/cloud/datastore_v1/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
    from google.cloud.datastore_v1 import types
2018-03-27 16:13:41.378 HKT
ImportError: cannot import name types
```

app.yaml file contents

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: web.app.app
libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: latest
```

appengine_config.py file contents

```
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the datastore client library, but this does not work in the standard environment. From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/#connecting_to_datastore_name_short_with_app_engine):

> You cannot use the Cloud Datastore client library with Python applications in the App Engine standard environment.

You need to use the [ndb](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/) package, as recommended in the docs (I believe there is also a REST API, but I've never used it).

Answer (score 1):

The first traceback appears to suggest that `grpc` is somehow involved, and that's a problem. According to comments on [issue 149](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-python/issues/149) `grpc` is not yet supported on GAE standard environment.

But since you're on the GAE standard environment you should really use the recommended, GAE-optimized (and more feature-rich) [NDB Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/) to access the datastore, not the generic `google.cloud.datastore` one (which *might* indeed include features not meeting the standard env sandbox restrictions).

Answer (score 1):

**(Jul 2020)** Google fixed this issue in 2019 so now, Python 2.7 apps running on Standard can use the `google.cloud.datastore` library. To get rid of the `grpc` error, add these lines to the `libraries` section of your `app.yaml` file (or add it if not there already):

```
libraries:
- name: grpcio
  version: 1.0.0
```

The statement from the accepted answer: "You cannot use the Cloud Datastore client library with Python applications in the App Engine standard environment," is no longer true and wiped from the docs.

If porting to [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore) from [the App Engine NDB library](http://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb) ( `google.appengine.ext.ndb`), it may be easier to first port to [the Cloud NDB library](https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest) (`google.cloud.ndb`, which is really just an "NDB client library" for Cloud Datastore). The step of adding the `grpcio` reference to `app.yaml` is described on [this migration page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/migrating-to-cloud-ndb#installing_the_cloud_ndb_library_for_python_2_apps).

Another reason for this intermediate port is that Cloud NDB is also available in Python 3, giving you the opportunity to migrate your app from 2.x to 3.x and still have things work. Plus you get the added benefit of using App Engine's 2nd generation runtimes (Gen1 std only supports 2.7 while Flex supports 2.7 or 3.x, and Gen2 only supports 3.x.)

Finally from there, port to [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview) (`google.cloud.datastore`). That intermediate step basically gets your "app infrastructure" ready for Cloud Datastore, and most of your heavy-lifting will be migrating your NDB data CRUDs to Cloud Datastore but not have to worry about these library issues which s/b taken care of by the above intermediate step. (I'll try to do a write-up on all this and will update this answer when I get something out there.)