# ImportError: No module named google.api_core

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, dialogflow-es

I received an error message: "No module named google.api_core".

When I include dialogflow into my source code.
I installed dialogflow by:

```
pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt
```

I'm using

```
python 2.7, dialogflow v2, google-api-core==0.1.4
```

[image: IMG - Error No module named google.api_core]

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Instead copy-paste and format it as needed. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a `google/api_core` dir under your app's `lib` dir?

Comment: Yes, I have it. That error occurred in the dev environment, and on the GAE standard environment it reported an error "ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function" (initcygrpc) ". It seems that dialogflow v2 is not really stable on GAE. Thank Dan!

Comment: It *might* not work in the standard env GAE due to grpc, I know it at some point it wasn't compatible with the sandbox limitations, but I didn't check the issue very closely, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527475/grpc-and-types-import-error-in-app-engine-datastore/49527825#49527825

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported issue in which the Engineering team is working on with no estimated time for resolution. It is possible to follow the developments in this [thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/77754217).

Comment: I am switching to using REST API dialogflow v2. Thank you very much!

Comment: The link is not a public (Google internal only)