# Can't import datastore in Google App Engine

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to import datastore to my code in GAE like this way,

```
from google.cloud import datastore
```

unfortunately I got some error message in stackdriver like this

```
     from grpc._cython import cygrpc as _cygrpc
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initcygrpc)
```

or like this

```
     from google.cloud.datastore_v1 import types 
ImportError: cannot import name types
```

anyone know the reason or something?
thanks in advance

====
env: standard
language: python
runtime: python27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the generic client datastore library, which is no longer compatible with the standard environment GAE sandbox restrictions. See related [GRPC and types import error in App Engine Datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527475/grpc-and-types-import-error-in-app-engine-datastore)

From [Google App Engine Standard Environment Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#google_app_engine_standard_environment_client_libraries):

> **Note**: For App Engine applications that are written in Python, the Google Datastore DB Client Library is no longer recommended; use the
>   Google Datastore NDB Client Library instead.

So switch to [NDB](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/) (I find it superior, with more functionality, optimized for GAE and better documented, right in the GAE-specific documentation area).