# Cannot import cygrpc on Google App Engine Standard

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, grpc, google-cloud-vision

I am attempting to use the Cloud Vision API on Google App Engine Standard with a Python 2.7 runtime.  However, I get the following error:

> File "/base/data/home/apps/s~qa-vm-randstadcentraldb/resumeparsertest:20190412t145531.417442728520489945/lib/grpc/**init**.py", line 22, in 
>       from grpc._cython import cygrpc as _cygrpc
>   ImportError: cannot import name cygrpc

This seems to be a known error per the thread [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/1540).  I executed the proposed solution into my lib directory like below, but I am still getting the same error message.

```
python -m pip install grcpio --ignore-installed -t ./lib
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Potentially related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51490175/cant-import-datastore-in-google-app-engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was attempting to use the Google Cloud Python libraries, which are only support on the the Python 3 runtime.

Per Google support the workaround is to use the Cloud Vision API Client Library for Python but there is no documentation for this.

I ended up migrating to Python 3 and App Engine Flex.