# How to call Google Talent Solution api from Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api

I'd like to use the Google Talent Solution (GTS).

The [set-up docs](https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/before-you-begin) explain how to set-up an Standard Env App Engine project using a service account. I've enabled GTS in my App Engine project, enabled Data Logging and added a `Service Account Token Creator` to the `App Engine default service account` that was created when I enabled GTS - `[app-id]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`.

I've [read the docs](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html) for a Python AppEngine project but it uses a [deprecated API oauth2client](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html) and I'm trying to use `google_auth` instead (I've installed and vendored `google_api` and `google_auth`.

In my vendor `appengine_config.py`:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
import os

google_api_path = "%s%s" % (os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '/applications/[app-id]/modules/google_api')
```

vendor.add(google_api_path)

```
google_auth = "%s%s" % (os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '/applications/[app-id]/modules/google')
```

vendor.add(google_auth)

I installed google_auth into a directory named `google`. And in a directory path `/applications/[app-id]/modules/` which works well with `Web2py`, a Python framework.

My code:

```
from google.auth import app_engine
credentials = app_engine.Credentials()
print(credentials.token)
```

Alas, `credentials.token` is `None`

In all this set-up, config and code, what have I missed?

Comment: I've missed setting up `a security requirement object and a security definitions object in your OpenAPI configuration file to support authentication of a calling service`. trying this.

Comment: having added the OpenAPI config file the call to app_engine.Credentials() still return an object with the token member set to None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making the changes (which I've added to my question) the calls work!

Because I'm using a Service Account `credentials.token` is None and I can proceed to call a Google Talent Solution to add, for example, companies.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because the `oauth2client` has been deprecated. From [googleapis/oauth2client](https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client):

> **Note**: oauth2client is now deprecated. No more features will be added to the libraries and the core team is turning down support. We
>   recommend you use [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/) and [oauthlib](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/). For more details
>   on the deprecation, see [oauth2client deprecation](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html).

But I see `google-auth` uses `gRPC`, which at least not long ago wasn't compatible with standard environment GAE apps, see [GRPC and types import error in App Engine Datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527475/grpc-and-types-import-error-in-app-engine-datastore/49527825#49527825), so YMMV.

Comment: Thanks. That’s very constructive.

Comment: I've rewritten the question based on progress I've made. google_auth installed and callable but credentials are not being returned