# ImportError: cannot import name cygrpc

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use Firebase Native mode on Google App Engine - Standard. My python language is Python 2.7. When I try to from google.cloud import firestore, I get an error ImportError: cannot import name cygrpc

I have deployed virtualenv described in the documentation  [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers).

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
```

My appengine_config.py is

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
import os.path

# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'lib'))
```

my_app.py includes

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.api import mail

import os

from google.cloud import firestore



(/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/43d5822312de17fd/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:269)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/43d5822312de17fd/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/43d5822312de17fd/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 311, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/43d5822312de17fd/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~openbarn-prod/20190602t102855.418624175446659791/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from controllers import server, common, header
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~openbarn-prod/20190602t102855.418624175446659791/controllers/server.py", line 10, in <module>
    from google.cloud import firestore
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~openbarn-prod/20190602t102855.418624175446659791/lib/google/cloud/firestore.py", line 18, in <module>
    from google.cloud.firestore_v1 import __version__
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~openbarn-prod/20190602t102855.418624175446659791/lib/google/cloud/firestore_v1/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from google.cloud.firestore_v1._helpers import GeoPoint
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~openbarn-prod/20190602t102855.418624175446659791/lib/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 21, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~openbarn-prod/20190602t102855.418624175446659791/lib/grpc/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc as _cygrpc
ImportError: cannot import name cygrpc
```

The question I have - can you use Firestore Native mode on Google App Engine Standard using Python 2.7? I need GAE- Standard because we are using Google Endpoint that is not support on GAE-Flex.

The doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore) says App Engine Client library integration is not supported on Python2.7 GAE Standard environment. But I am not trying App Engine Client library, I am trying App Engine Server library in GAE Standard Environment.
How do I solve for import error for cygrpc? The solution [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15856), says -

```
python -m pip install grpcio --ignore-installed
```

Is this recommended?

Comment: The product team recommends App Engine and other compute-backed apps use Cloud Firestore in **Datastore** mode and *not* Native mode. The latter is more appropriate for mobile and client-side web apps that need Firestore in a BaaS capacity which is more suited for Native/Firebase access. IOW, if you have SOME kind of server, whether serverless, VMs, Kubernetes, etc., it's best to use Datastore mode.  Also see this page in the docs for more info: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while ago GRPC wasn't supported on GAE standard, see [GRPC and types import error in App Engine Datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527475/grpc-and-types-import-error-in-app-engine-datastore/49527825#49527825). I didn't try since, but I don't see newer activity on [issue 149](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-python/issues/149).

Also the `cython` reference in the traceback suggests that it may include compiled code, which would violate the [pure python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#Python_Pure_Python) standard environment sandbox restrictions that applies to the code you deploy.

Comment: Dan - So can you confirm that we CANNOT use Firestore Native mode on Google App Engine Standard using Python 2.7?

Comment: Without the client library (and GRPC for communication) I'm pretty sure that's what it means. I jumped straight to the traceback and actually missed the main question ;)

Comment: You could use the Firestore REST API

Answer (score 2):

It's 2020, and you can now use `grpcio` (without explicitly adding it yourself as it's a built-in library) w/Cloud Firestore natively on App Engine with Python 2.7. Three things to make this work:

1. Add `google-cloud-firestore` to your `requirements.txt` file and install with `pip install -U -t lib -r requirements.txt`.
2. Add these lines to the `libraries` section of your `app.yaml` file:

```
libraries:
- name: grpcio
  version: 1.0.0
- name: setuptools
  version: 36.6.0
```

3. Ensure these lines are in your `appengine_config.py` file:

```
import pkg_resources
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Set path to your libraries folder.
path = 'lib'
# Add libraries installed in the path folder.
vendor.add(path)
# Add libraries to pkg_resources working set to find the distribution.
pkg_resources.working_set.add_entry(path)
```

Of course, we do recommend you eventually [migrate to Python 3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3) to take advantage of the greater flexibility the next generations (of Python *and* App Engine) provide, esp. the ability to tap into other GCP services. *However*, caveat such a port isn't without effort if your app is complex & deeply-dependent on App Engine's 1st gen built-in services. Most of the suggestions above are derived from [this section of the migration docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrating-services#installing_libraries_for_python_2_apps).

Once you're on Python 3, everything related to 3P libraries on App Engine becomes *much easier*, as I demonstrate in [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67863189/305689).

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that your installed python version bit(32/64) and your system bit(32/64) are matched.
- If they are not matched please follow the solution mentioned at https://azurelessons.com/cannot-import-name-cygrpc/